# Where is less search pattern reference?

Tags: regular-expression, less

Where can I find reference for `less` regex search patterns?

I want to search file with `less` using `\d` to find digits, but it does not seem to understand this wildcard. I tried to find a reference for `less` regex patterns, but could not find anything, not on man pages and not on the Internet.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`less`'s man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html) says:

```
   /pattern
          Search forward in the file for the N-th line containing
          the pattern.  N defaults to 1.  The pattern is a regular
          expression, as recognized by the regular expression library
          supplied by your system.
```

so the accepted syntax may depend on your system. Off-hand, it seems to accept extended regular expressions on my Debian system, see [`regex(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html), and [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/170373)

`\d` is from Perl, and isn't supported by all regex engines. Use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` to match digits. (Their exact behaviour may depend on the locale.)

Comment: > *as recognized by the regular expression library supplied by your system.* < so… any way to direct `less` to `libpcre`?

Comment: I have Debian 10 according to lsb_release. If I run less on a file that contains a's and e's, and use the command `/a|e/`, less only highlights the a's. If I enter the command `/a\|e/` I get pattern not found. This tends to support that less is accepting the basic syntax, according to `man re_format`. If I made a mistake in trying to invoke extended syntax, please let me know.

Comment: @cardiffspaceman, did you put the trailing `/` there? I don't think `less` expects that, so it'll look for the string `e/` as the other alternative. It has to be extended regexes, since BRE doesn't have the alternation, and in BRE, `a|e` would look for that literal string

Comment: @likkachu leaving off the trailing `/` does make the command work as expected, extended RE.

Answer (score 17):

The expressions supported by `less` are documented in the `re_format(7)` manual (`man 7 re_format`).  That manual describes both the extended regular expressions and the basic regular expressions available on your system.  The `less` utility understands extended regular expressions.

To match a digit, you would use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` (there's a slight difference as the former depends on the current locale).  The `\d` pattern is a Perl-like regular expression (PCRE), not supported by `less`.