# Using regular expressions in "less"

Tags: regular-expression, less, case-sensitivity

I'm trying to use a regular expression in the man page of Bash by using `less`.

I press <kbd>/</kbd> in `less` to enter a pattern, and I type `z` and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I expected it to not match upper-case `z` (`Z`), but it does.

How do I make it not match `Z`? What kind of regular expressions are these that are not case sensitive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is less search pattern reference?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453234/where-is-less-search-pattern-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's explained in the man page for `less`.

The default action for REs is to ignore case if there are no uppercase characters present, but to act case-sensitively otherwise.

There are three modes available within `less`:

1. Case context dependent: a search or RE without uppercase characters is considered to be case-insensitive, but a search or RE containing at least one uppercase character is considered to be case-sensitive. Examples: `abc` will match `abc` and `aBC`, but `aBc` will only match `aBc` and not `abc` or `ABC`. This is the default setting.
2. Case sensitive: a search or RE pays full regard to the case of any letter. Example: `abC` will match only `abC` and not `abc` or `ABC`.
3. Case insensitive: a search or RE pays no regard to the case of any letter. Example: `abC` will match any of `abc`, `abC`, or `ABC`.

You can toggle case sensitive comparisons with `-I`, and case context sensitive comparisons with `-i`.

The control can be specified in three ways:

- On the command line, for example `less -I bigfile.txt`.
- In the environment, for example `export LESS=-i` and later `less bigfile.txt`.
- Within `less` itself, for example by starting `less bigfile.txt` and then typing `-i`.

Comment: Hey, roaima. I think this is incorrect.
```
-i or --ignore-case
Causes searches to ignore case; that is, uppercase and lowercase are considered identical. This option is ignored if any uppercase letters appear in the search pattern; in other words, if a pattern contains uppercase letters, then that search does not ignore case.
-I or --IGNORE-CASE
Like -i, but searches ignore case even if the pattern contains uppercase letters.
```
From my experiments, it behaves as `-I`, not as `-i`.

Comment: You could also append `|$A` (which translates as _or A after the end of the line_) for your pattern to become case sensitive without having to the change the settings.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that's thrown me. I had thought `$` was only special at the end of an RE (or RE clause), so `$A` would match a dollar and a capital letter, but `A$` would match a capital at the end of a line. (Update: I can't even mimic this with `perl`, but definitely works with `less`.)

Comment: @roaima, it's different between BRE and ERE, POSIX requires BRE `$a` to match on `$a`, and ERE `$a` to not match (`$` to match the end of the subject wherever it's found). In Perl/PCRE, `$` matches at the end of the subject or before a trailing line delimiter at the end of the subject, or if the `m` flag is enabled (`(?m)`) at the end of the subject or before any line delimiter in the subject.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you can get around that by using `-i` or `+i` in order to set less to default.